# Problema em consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Está dando o erro Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in. Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
$mes = date('m');
$ano = date('Y');

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE empresa='empresa' AND MONTH(data_atendimento) = '$mes' AND YEAR(data_atendimento) = '$ano'");
$numRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Comment: Ola, acredito que o erro esteja na consulta possivelmente em um dos parametros depois do where tenta remover estes parametros e executar a consulta novamente para ver se irá executar normalmente e caso adiciona algum parametro no where e ocorra o erro pode identificar qual deles está inserido errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guilherme, pode ser que tenha algum erro na montagem da consulta.
A palavra `'empresa'` está sem o cifrão `$`. Se ela for uma variável, está incorreta ali.
Nesse caso, a consulta retorna `false`.

Sugiro o seguinte código:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE empresa='$empresa' AND 
    MONTH(data_atendimento) = '$mes' AND YEAR(data_atendimento) = '$ano'";

if (!$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
   echo 'Sem registros...';
} else {
    $numRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso empresa não é uma variavel

Comment: @GuilhermeFreitas Entendi... você tem acesso ao ambiente do banco de dados para fazer o teste usando esse Select direto nele? De qualquer forma, implemente essa sugestão que dei, pois se não tiver registros para a consulta, o `mysqli_query` vai retornar `false`